# Three.js: Rotate object on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, rotation, mobile-devices

Referring to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449582/three-js-stop-automatic-rotation-while-mouse-is-clicked), I am trying to get an object rotated on smartphones/tablets. Since I got it with `mouseDown` method, this won't apply to the touching on mobile devices. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009821/how-to-impliment-a-onmousedown-and-onmouseup-on-a-touch-screen-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `touchstart` and `touchend` as the event listeners for touch screens.

```
window.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
window.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
```